# How to get Youtube url from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, video, youtube

I'm trying to display a list of submitted youtube videos through this code

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
            echo  "
            <iframe width=\"160\" height=\"120\"  frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen src=".$row['videourl']."></iframe>
        </div>";
}mysql_free_result($qry);
```

However the video is not displaying due to the following error :
**Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_whatever' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.**

1) Does this have anything to with testing the code on a localhost and might resolve when uploaded on a true domain?

2)Is this a good approach to echo youtube videos via a php form and a mysql database ?

3)What can I do to overcome the problem?

NOTE: After googling the error I understood its something to with youtube not allowing its iframe to display on any other domain, but that's why I'd like to know if a localhost "domain" might be causing this...

Comment: Try to change your header X-Frame-Options from SAMEORIGIN to <php header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save embed url for the video in the database . then you can use like this

```
 <object width="420" height="315"
data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</object>
```

or second method is

```
<embed width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
```

after that this code will work.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
            echo  "
            <iframe width=\"160\" height=\"120\"  frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen src=".$row['videourl']."></iframe>
        </div>";
}mysqli_free_result($qry);
```

**2nd option is**

Just pick the video code at the end of link

for example

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahg6qcgoay4` from this link get `Ahg6qcgoay4` and create link like `http://www.youtube.com/v/Ahg6qcgoay4` in your code

then use something like this

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
                echo  "
                <iframe width=\"160\" height=\"120\"  frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen src='http://www.youtube.com/v/".$code."'></iframe>
            </div>";
    }mysqli_free_result($qry);
```

Comment: Problem solved, correct embedding address/link solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way to handle this one is split the URL before you save it into database and extract `_whatever` out of it.
2. When you get this extracted out of database then do as follows:

   `<iframe width='160' height='120'  frameborder='0' allowfullscreen src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$row['videourl']."'></iframe>`

The reason being the Youtube URLs are of two types generally

```
 i. 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_whatever'
ii. 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/_whatever'
```

The better practice while doing with `<iframe>` is using `ii.` URL